# When jquery defer, the menu js file gives an error and the menu does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Source of JS File: https://kargotakip.co/kargom-nerede/themes/trackco/js/customscript.js

[**Desktop and mobile menu not working. Click for picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8KHs.png)

This js file is controlling the dropdown in my theme. Unfortunately, when I defer the jquery library, it gives this error. But if jquery doesn't defer, if the script loads normally, it works fine.

```js
jQuery.fn.exists = function(callback) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (this.length) {
        callback.call(this, args);
    }
    return this;
};


/*----------------------------------------------------
/* Make all anchor links smooth scrolling
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 // scroll handler
    var scrollToAnchor = function( id, event ) {
        // grab the element to scroll to based on the name
        var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
        // if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
        if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) === "undefined" ) {
            elem = $("#"+id);
        }
        // if the destination element exists
        if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) !== "undefined" ) {
            // cancel default event propagation
            event.preventDefault();

            // do the scroll
            // also hide mobile menu
            var headerHeight = $("#header.sticky-navigation").height() + 15; // Get fixed header height
            if( headerHeight > 0 ){
                var scroll_to = elem.offset().top-headerHeight;
            } else {
                var scroll_to = elem.offset().top;
            }
            $('html, body').removeClass('mobile-menu-active').animate({
                            scrollTop: scroll_to
            }, 600, 'swing', function() { if (scroll_to > 46) window.location.hash = id; } );
        }
    };
    // bind to click event
    $("a").click(function( event ) {
        // only do this if it's an anchor link
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var exclude = ['#tab-description', '#tab-additional_information', '#tab-reviews'];
        if (exclude.includes(href)) {
            return;
        }
        if ( href && href.match("#") && href !== '#' ) {
            // scroll to the location
            var parts = href.split('#'),
                url = parts[0],
                target = parts[1];
            if ((!url || url == window.location.href.split('#')[0]) && target)
                scrollToAnchor( target, event );
        }
    });
});


/*----------------------------------------------------
/* Responsive Navigation
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
if (mts_customscript.responsive && mts_customscript.nav_menu != 'none') {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#secondary-navigation').append('<div id="mobile-menu-overlay" />');
                // merge if two menus exist
                if (mts_customscript.nav_menu == 'both' && !$('.navigation.mobile-only').length) {
                        $('.navigation').not('.mobile-menu-wrapper').find('.menu').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu-wrapper').hide();
                }
                $('nav').find('.header-social-icons').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu-wrapper').hide();
                $('nav').find('.mts-cart').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu-wrapper').hide();

                $('.toggle-mobile-menu').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $('body').toggleClass('mobile-menu-active');

                        if ( $('body').hasClass('mobile-menu-active') ) {
                                if ( $(document).height() > $(window).height() ) {
                                        var scrollTop = ( $('html').scrollTop() ) ? $('html').scrollTop() : $('body').scrollTop();
                                        $('html').addClass('noscroll').css( 'top', -scrollTop );
                                }
                                $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeIn();
                        } else {
                                var scrollTop = parseInt( $('html').css('top') );
                                $('html').removeClass('noscroll');
                                $('html,body').scrollTop( -scrollTop );
                                $('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeOut();
                        }
                });
    **}).on('click', function(event) {
        var $target = jQuery(event.target);
        if ( ( $target.hasClass("fa") && $target.parent().hasClass("toggle-caret") ) ||  $target.hasClass("toggle-caret") ) {// allow clicking on menu toggles
            return;
        }
        jQuery('body').removeClass('mobile-menu-active');
        jQuery('html').removeClass('noscroll');
        jQuery('#mobile-menu-overlay').fadeOut();
    });**

}

/*----------------------------------------------------
/*  Dropdown menu
/* ------------------------------------------------- */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        let $pullToggle = $('#pull');
        function mtsDropdownMenu() {
                if(!$pullToggle.is(':visible')) {
                        let timer;
                        let delay = 100;
                        $('.navigation li').hover(function (e) {
                            if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                let $this = $(this);
                                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                                    $this.children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').slideDown('fast');
                                }, delay);
                            }
                            else if (e.type === 'mouseleave') {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $(this).children('ul.sub-menu, ul.children').hide(1);
                                clearTimeout(timer);
                            }
                        });
                        
                        } else {
                            $('.navigation li').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
                            //$('.navigation li.active > ul.sub-menu, .navigation li.active > ul.children').show();
                        }
        }

        mtsDropdownMenu();

        $(window).resize(function() {
                mtsDropdownMenu();
        });
});

/*---------------------------------------------------
/*  Vertical menus toggles
/* -------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.widget_nav_menu, .navigation .menu').addClass('toggle-menu');
        $('.toggle-menu ul.sub-menu, .toggle-menu ul.children').addClass('toggle-submenu');
        $('.toggle-menu ul.sub-menu').parent().addClass('toggle-menu-item-parent');

        $('.toggle-menu .toggle-menu-item-parent').append('<span class="toggle-caret"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>');

        $('.toggle-caret').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').children('.toggle-submenu').slideToggle('fast');
        });
});

/*----------------------------------------------------
/* Social button scripts
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    (function(d, s) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], load = function(url, id) {
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.src = url; js.id = id;
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        };
    jQuery('span.facebookbtn, span.facebooksharebtn, .facebook_like').exists(function() {
        load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8', 'fbjssdk');
    });
    jQuery('span.twitterbtn').exists(function() {
        load('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 'tweetjs');
    });
    jQuery('span.linkedinbtn').exists(function() {
        load('//platform.linkedin.com/in.js', 'linkedinjs');
    });
    jQuery('span.pinbtn').exists(function() {
        load('//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js', 'pinterestjs');
    });
    jQuery('span.stumblebtn').exists(function() {
        load('//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js', 'stumbleuponjs');
    });
    }(document, 'script'));
});

/*----------------------------------------------------
/* Lazy load avatars
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
if ( mts_customscript['lazy_load_comments'] ) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                var lazyloadAvatar = function(){
                        $('.comment-author .avatar').each(function(){
                                var distanceToTop = $(this).offset().top;
                                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                                var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                                var isVisible = distanceToTop - scroll < windowHeight;
                                if( isVisible ){
                                        var hashedUrl = $(this).attr('data-src');
                                        if ( hashedUrl ) {
                                                $(this).attr('src',hashedUrl).removeClass('loading');
                                        }
                                }
                        });
                };
                if ($('.comment-author .avatar').length > 0) {
                    $('.comment-author .avatar').each(function (i, el) {
                        $(el).attr('data-src', el.src).removeAttr('src').addClass('loading');
                    });
                    $(function () {
                        $(window).scroll(function () {
                            lazyloadAvatar();
                        });
                    });
                    //lazyloadAvatar();
                }
        });
}

/*
* Detect browser width for sticky navigation
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // check mobile width
    function checkmobilesize() {
        var wi = $(window).width();
        if (wi <= 865) {
            $header = $('#header');
            if ($header.hasClass('sticky-navigation')) {
                $header.removeClass('sticky-navigation');
            }
            if ($header.hasClass('sticky-navigation-active')) {
                $header.removeClass('sticky-navigation-active');
            }
            $('#catcher').remove();
        }
    }
    // check desktop width
    function checkdesktopsize() {
        var wi = $(window).width();
        if (wi > 865) {
            $header = $('#header');
            if (!$header.hasClass('sticky-navigation')) {
                $header.addClass('sticky-navigation');
            }
        }
    }
    if ('0' == mts_customscript.mobile_sticky) {
        checkmobilesize();
    }
    $(window).resize(function ($) {
        if ('0' == mts_customscript.mobile_sticky) {
            checkmobilesize();
            if ('1' == mts_customscript.desktop_sticky) {
                checkdesktopsize();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to load the jquery.min.js file with async but still no result. In Lighthouse, jquery.min.js wastes a lot of time and lowers my pagespeed score. For this reason, I want to install jquery.min.js as a defer, but the menu does not work.

Comment: *But if jquery doesn't defer, if the script loads normally, it works fine.* - then that's your answer - jquery is not about performance, it's about simplifying HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation - it allows one piece of code to be run on very OLD browsers all the way to modern browsers, so you don't have to worry about compatibility. If you want perfomant code, don't use jquery

Comment: to clarify *jquery is not about performance* - of course it is about performance, but the **main** goal is compatibility between a large number of browsers old and new. So, performance often takes a back seat to compatibility. The best example (for me) is, `$.each` on Arrays (and Array-like objects) - we had "cut-and-paste" coders that religiously used `$.each` everywhere - I went through and changed 99% of them to `Array#forEach` and our site performance improved so much, our clients thought something was wrong!